# How to check if user is using Android browser?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2

My Util.java contains following method:

```
public static boolean isAndroid(HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean retVal = false;     
    String browser = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
    if (browser != null && !browser.trim().equals("") && browser.contains("Android")) {
        retVal = true;
    }       
    return retVal;
}
```

And I've below code in BaseAction.java (it also has request variable of type HttpServletRequest) which extends ActionSupport & implements ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware.

```
public boolean isAndroid(){
  return Util.isAndroid(request);
}
```

Now, I want to check in JSP if device is android & if it is perform certain action, so I'm using below code:

```
<s:if test="%{#android=='false'}">
   <a href="/myUrl"></a>
</s:if>
<s:else>
  ....
</s:else>
```

But the above code doesn't seem to work. Can any one suggest why its not working & if there is another way to check in JSP to see if user is using Android browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing against the string `"false"` but should be checking against an actual boolean, and can use `<s:if test="android">` or `<s:if test="!android">` as required.

Also, you're prefixing the property name with a `#`, which is not necessary for values pushed on to the stack--the `#` character is only for *named* values in the stack context.

All that said, why bother doing it that way?

Answer (score 3):

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
boolean isAndroid = (userAgent != null && !userAgent.isEmpty() && userAgent.toLowerCase().contains("android"));
```

Answer (score 1):

in jsp

```
<c:set var="browser" value="${header['User-Agent']}" scope="session"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think below javascript code would be helpful to you;

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
// Do some action you want to!
}
```

Just check it out..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this EL you are using here? As I remember $ is the character we use in EL, instead of % character in your code.  And I don't think you need to use single quote with 'false' when comparing with android property. So I think this should work. But check whether you can access "android" variable in your page first. Check whether following codes are working.

```
<s:if test="${android eq false}">
   <a href="/myUrl"></a>
</s:if>
```

OR

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<s:if test="${fn:contains(header['User-Agent'],'Android'}">
   <a href="/myUrl"></a>
</s:if>
```

Comment: The `%{}` is Struts 2's OGNL escape; it is not JSP EL.