# how to detect from user-agent whether the request is coming from android-app or android-browser

Tags: android, user-agent, device-detection

**User-Agent for iPhone Browser**

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us)
>   AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) ***Version***/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293
>   Safari/6531.22.7

**User-Agent for iPhone App**

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X, en-us)
>   AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7D11.

I have tried to detect through "VERSION" keyword as in case of iPhone but it is not working in android Device.

Comment: which backend language you are using ?

Comment: See: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent#webview_user_agent

Comment: @satyen, I am using java..but just need sample user-agent for both android-app and android browser to differentiate among them.

Comment: can you have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802662/how-to-check-if-user-is-using-android-browser